# C++: matplotlibcpp.h and Python.h linker error

Tags: c++, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

I am finding trouble linking a library in C++.

I am trying for the first time to use "matplotlibcpp.h". This is a library that uses "Python.h"

My code is not using either of the libraries yet. It gives error just by including "matplotlibcpp". I am using python2.7 and Ubuntu 18.04 and am using Eclipse.

The code does not run if I include:

```
#include "matplotlibcpp.h" // programme runs if this is commented out. But I need it to add new features.
#include "Python.h"
```

I have added these paths in several futile attempts (they solved similar issues to other threads):

```
GCC C++ Compiler, include paths (-l)

/home/toni/Programs/Workspace/Libraries/matplotlib-cpp-master/
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy
/usr/include/python2.7
```

```
GCC C++ Linker, Library search path (-L)

/home/toni/Programs/Workspace/Libraries/matplotlib-cpp-master/
/usr/lib/python2.7/config-i386-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/include/python2.7
```

The programme builds, but does not run:

```
Finished building: ../src/WindProfilesCoursera.cpp

Building target: WindProfilesCoursera
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/home/toni/Programs/Workspace/Libraries/matplotlib-cpp-master/ -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config-i386-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/python2.7 -L/usr/include/python2.7 -o "WindProfilesCoursera"  ./src/WindProfilesCoursera.o   
./src/WindProfilesCoursera.o: In function `_import_array':
/usr/include/python2.7/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1456: undefined reference to `PyImport_ImportModule'
makefile:45: recipe for target 'WindProfilesCoursera' failed
/usr/include/python2.7/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1460: undefined reference to `PyExc_ImportError'
/usr/include/python2.7/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1460: undefined reference to `PyErr_SetString'
/usr/include/python2.7/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1463: undefined reference to `PyObject_GetAttrString'
/usr/include/python2.7/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1466: undefined reference to `PyExc_AttributeError'
/usr/include/python2.7/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1466: undefined reference to `PyErr_SetString'
/usr/include/python2.7/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1478: undefined reference to `PyCObject_Type'
/usr/include/python2.7/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1479: undefined reference to `PyExc_RuntimeError'
/usr/include/python2.7/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1479: undefined reference to `PyErr_SetString'
/usr/include/python2.7/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1483: undefined reference to `PyCObject_AsVoidPtr'
/usr/include/python2.7/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1487: undefined reference to `PyExc_RuntimeError'
/usr/include/python2.7/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1487: undefined reference to `PyErr_SetString'
/usr/include/python2.7/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1493: undefined reference to `PyExc_RuntimeError'
/usr/include/python2.7/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1493: undefined reference to `PyErr_Format'
/usr/include/python2.7/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1499: undefined reference to `PyExc_RuntimeError'
/usr/include/python2.7/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1499: undefined reference to `PyErr_Format'
/usr/include/python2.7/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1511: undefined reference to `PyExc_RuntimeError'
/usr/include/python2.7/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1511: undefined reference to `PyErr_Format'
/usr/include/python2.7/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1522: undefined reference to `PyExc_RuntimeError'
/usr/include/python2.7/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1522: undefined reference to `PyErr_Format'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [WindProfilesCoursera] Error 1
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

20:35:04 Build Failed. 22 errors, 1 warnings. (took 2s.454ms)
```