# How to link python.h and matplotlibcpp.h in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, matplotlib, header

From a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65998756/how-to-install-matplotlib-cpp-h-for-visual-studio-2019), one installed [package matplotlib-cpp](https://matplotlib-cpp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) through [microsoft /
vcpkg](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg#vcpkg-with-visual-studio-cmake-projects) . However, when running a [simple example](https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp),

```
#include "matplotlibcpp.h"
namespace plt = matplotlibcpp;
int main() {
    plt::plot({1,3,2,4});
    plt::show();
}
```

an error returned stating that

```
Error C1083 Cannot open include file: 'Python.h': No such file or directory Examples
..\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\matplotlibcpp.h  5
```

I have tried the methods in:

1. [can't include Python.h in visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44533679/cant-include-python-h-in-visual-studio)
2. [psycopg: Python.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843945/psycopg-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory) and [Cygwin gcc issue - cannot find Python.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21843714/cygwin-gcc-issue-cannot-find-python-h) (which didn't apply since vs managed python environment itself, and there wasn't python-dev option)
3. A very similiar post [C++: matplotlibcpp.h and Python.h linker error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62312002/c-matplotlibcpp-h-and-python-h-linker-error) also indicated the same issue in Ubuntu environment.

In [matplotlibcpp.h](https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp/blob/master/matplotlibcpp.h) file, it mentioned that

```
// Python headers must be included before any system headers, since
// they define _POSIX_C_SOURCE
#include <Python.h>
```

What did it mean? How to link python.h and a matplotlibcpp.h in Visual Studio 2019?

---

Updates:
I was able to locate "Python.h" and "numpy/arrayobject.h" in MS python folder. However, when I manually added those three ".h" files into the project header folder, the issue wasn't resolved. Especially, when I manually fixed the locations in "matplotlibcpp.h", the "Python.h" in ""numpy/arrayobject.h" still could not be located.